# Why did Erin say the "Big Brothers" while opening the shed with a knife?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-texas-chainsaw-massacre-2003

In **[The Texas Chainsaw Massacre](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0324216/)** (2003 unrated), Why did Erin say the words "***Big Brothers***" to Pepper while opening the shed lock with a knife?

[image]

Comment: I believe that this is a remake of the 1974 original.  In the original, there were two siblings Sally and Franklin.  Franklin was in a wheelchair and Sally was the sole survivor at the end of the movie.  I have only seen this 2003 remake once, but I believe that Erin does survive at the end, so perhaps one of the male passengers in the van was her brother and she was just complaining about him...like Sally does in the original when she complains about Franklin.